# font of an app name installed in iphone

Tags: ios

I want to know the font of an installed app name in IOS.

I am not talking about the fonts being used in an app.
When app is installed on an iphone, we see a name for it. I want to know what is font of it by default? Is there a way to change the font of it?

Comment: Are you talking about the font used by iOS on the Home screen showing the app names under the app icons?

Comment: Yes. That is what I am asking about.

Comment: Then you should update your question to make that more clear. BTW - this isn't a programming question. Try asking on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: For iOS 9 the font is [San Francisco](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/).

Answer (score 1):

Its the default apple font (System font) used by the iOS and it varies from iOS8 to iOS9. If you want to change the display font below the Application Icon on your home screen you actually cannot do it.